# Capture after positive lookbehind except is string contains exclusions in R

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following strings to parse for use in `R`:

```
PIA+1+TC_5504_00_312010_0050+50103 AB346 type 5334
PIA+1+TC_3444_00_312010_0133+0140
PIA+1+DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW
PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312019_2644+LoremIpsum
PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312010_0040+63503 AB346 type 5334
PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312018_0223+DolorSit
PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312019_2644+DolorSit
```

In a nutshell, the logic is this:

1. Capture everything after the positive lookbehind `(?<=^PIA\+\d{1}\+)`
2. Do not capture where the string contains either `LoremIpsum` or `DolorSit`

The desired output should look like this:

```
TC_5504_00_312010_0050+50103 AB346 type 5334
TC_3444_00_312010_0133+0140
DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW
TC_5635_00_312010_0040+63503 AB346 type 5334
```

This is where I got to thus far:

```
(?<=^PIA\+\d{1}\+)((?!.*LoremIpsum|DolorSit).)*$
```

I have deliberately not escaped according to `R` yet but will do so later.

But unfortunately it keeps the last digit of the capture into a new group. My experience in regex is limited and I am stuck how to capture the entire remaining string in a group. I am not bound to this approach and another logic could be, that whenever the last `+` is followed by a letter, it should exclude the capture but that would result in difficulties adding occasions with the `PIA+1+DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW` strings.

My samples are stored here [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HJxFSe/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the inefficient tempered greedy token completely by replacing it with a mere alternation group:

```
(?<=^PIA\+\d\+)(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit)).*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZBJ8T/2)

**Details**

- `(?<=` - a positive lookbehind that, immediately to the left of the current location, requires

  - `^` - start of string
  - `PIA\+` - `PIA+`
  - `\d` - one digit
  - `\+` - a `+`
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then followed with `LoremIpsum` or `DolorSit` substrings immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*$` - rest of the line.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/FyDeFE):

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("PIA+1+TC_5504_00_312010_0050+50103 AB346 type 5334",
"PIA+1+TC_3444_00_312010_0133+0140",
"PIA+1+DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW",
"PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312019_2644+LoremIpsum",
"PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312010_0040+63503 AB346 type 5334",
"PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312018_0223+DolorSit",
"PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312019_2644+DolorSit")
str_extract(x, "(?<=^PIA\\+\\d\\+)(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit)).*$")
```

Output:

```
[1] "TC_5504_00_312010_0050+50103 AB346 type 5334"
[2] "TC_3444_00_312010_0133+0140"                 
[3] "DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW"                   
[4] NA                                            
[5] "TC_5635_00_312010_0040+63503 AB346 type 5334"
[6] NA                                            
[7] NA
```

Or, you may also just get the matching strings using

```
res <- sub("^PIA\\+\\d\\+(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit))(.*)|.*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
res[res != ""]
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/txsS6v).

Or, if you need to just `grep` these strings:

```
grep("^PIA\\+\\d\\+(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit))", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/WiILjO). Output:

```
[1] "PIA+1+TC_5504_00_312010_0050+50103 AB346 type 5334"
[2] "PIA+1+TC_3444_00_312010_0133+0140"                 
[3] "PIA+1+DRW/50488665600/01/000:DW"                   
[4] "PIA+1+TC_5635_00_312010_0040+63503 AB346 type 5334"
```

Comment: Thanks again @Wiktor. Seems I got a lot to catch up to do on regex. This solution works perfectly fine.

Comment: the expression worked on the sample set but after escaping according to `R` as such `(?<=^PIA\\+\\d\\+(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit))).*$` and running the script, I get a error message, that lookbehind patterns must have a bounded maximum length `(U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT). I suppose this is due to the nested lookahead in the lookbehind ?

Comment: @Max What is the function you are using? `str_extract`?

Comment: yes I do, apologies. I wasn't aware that this information is relevant. `str_extract(x, "(?<=^PIA\\+\\d\\+(?!.*(?:LoremIpsum|DolorSit))).*$")`

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, so you basically closed-off the lookbehind in own parentheses and subsequently called the lookahead in its own group. I wasn't aware of the limitations in `str_extract()` ! The `grep` example is helpful, too as I have multiple cases where I got stuck on unlimited lookbehinds. I can confirm that this works as expected within the script. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Max Just for completeness, I also added https://ideone.com/txsS6v.